# How can I type this function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

When I'm build the project it shows in 2 functions, Please help me!!

1st error is:

```
Argument of type 'IFilmCard[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFilmCard[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IFilmCard[]'
 
export function __filterFilms(crts: [string, string?], arr: IFilmCard[]) {
    return __filterByGenre(crts[0], __filterByYear(crts[1], arr))
}
```

2nd error is:

```
Argument of type 'IPersonCard[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IPersonCard[]'.Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IPersonCard[]'


export function __filterPersons(crts: [string, string?], arr: IPersonCard[]) {
    return __filterByCountry(crts[0], __filterByYearsPersons(crts[1], arr))
}
```

Comment: Set an empty array as default value for the `arr` parameter on both functions `arr: IFilmCard[] = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable is a IPersonCard[] and if it cannot be undefined you can add 'as IPersonCard[]' after your attribution. But you will loose the benefit of Typescript checking.
This error means that your data could be a IPersonCard[] but it could also be undefined and you did not check it before.